# How can I add my own toolbar option in flutter SelectableText Toolbar

Tags: android, flutter, dart

How can I add a toolbar option like "**Find**" in the SelectableText Widget.

[image]

The doc isn't satisfying I saw a demo in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZSU3ZXOs6hc

Answer (score 0):

This is separate widget for `Text()` to provide toolbar options just like we have in `TextField()` toolbarOptions property.

```
TextField(
  toolbarOptions: ToolbarOptions(
  copy: true,
  cut: true,
  paste:true,
  selectAll: true,
  ),
)
```